# update in php not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

i update php form and change the value but it cant change it saves the same previous value

```
<tr>
  <td width="22%">Course Fees</td>
  <td width="38%">
    <div id="total_fees">
      <input type="text" class="input_text" name="total_fees" id="toal_fees"  onblur="show_record(this.value,1)" value="<?php if($_POST['total_fees']) echo $_POST['total_fees']; else echo $row['total_fees'];?>" />
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Please see the screenshot of source code and input filed . i changed the value in input field but it remain same in source code and save source code value db

[image]

Comment: Can you submit your form and check? You will get new value in request data.

Comment: Where is the query to save & how you are placing data in query?

Comment: Please see the screenshot of my answer

Comment: $total_fees=($_POST['total_fees']) ? $_POST['total_fees'] : "0";

Comment: $data_record['total_fees']=$total_fees;

Comment: $courses_id=$db->query_insert("enroll", $data_record);

Answer (score 0):

The input values not immediately affect on your input but You will get your new value while you submitting your form.

So submit your form and then print the values of the Request. You will find the new value of total_fees into the request parameters.

Comment: but when i submit the form, it saves the previous value in db, the changed value not saved

Comment: Can you print the values (After submitting form) before it's save to your database?

Comment: Yes i print but its print the previous value

Answer (score 0):

---

**HTML CODE**

```
<form name="jqueryForm" method="post" id="jqueryForm"  enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validme();">

    <table border="0" cellspacing="15" cellpadding="0" width="100%" >
    <tr>
                        <td width="22%">Course Fees</td>
                        <td width="38%">
                        <div id=total_fees>

                        <input type="text" class="input_text" name="total_fees" id="toal_fees"  onblur="show_record(this.value,1)" value="<?php if($_POST['total_fees']) echo $_POST['total_fees']; else echo $row['total_fees'];?>" />
                        </div>
                        </td>                
                        <td width="40%"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="22%">Discount in <input type="radio" name='discount_type' value="<?php if($_POST['discount_type']) echo $_POST['discount_type']; else echo percent; ?>" checked="checked" onChange="show_record()" />% or <input type="radio" name='discount_type' value="<?php if($_POST['discount_type']) echo $_POST['discount_type']; else echo cash; ?>" onChange="show_record()" />Cash</td>
                        <td width="38%"><input type="text" class="input_text" name="concession" id="concession" value="<?php if($_POST['concession']) echo $_POST['concession']; else if($row_record['discount'] !=0) echo $row_record['discount']; else echo 0; ?>" onBlur="show_record()"/>
                        </td>
                        <td width="40%"></td>
                    </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Record" name="save_changes" />
    </form>
```

---

**PHP CODE FOR SAVE IN DB**

```
if(isset($_POST['save_changes']))
{
$total_fees=($_POST['total_fees']) ? $_POST['total_fees'] : "0";
$data_record['total_fees']=$total_fees;
$courses_id=$db->query_insert("enroll", $data_record);  
}
```

---